# How many missions are available right now in Hitman (2016)?

Tags: hitman-series

This game was released yesterday and it's hard to find actual facts because Square Enix kept changing things.

I just completed the first contract in Paris called "The Showstopper". Now the only thing available to me is a cinematic called "The secrets of the global elite".

Is that really it? Nothing else until april?

Comment: Did you watch the Cinematic? I'd think maybe more stuff unlocks after that?....

Comment: Yeah, twice. It just sends me back to the menu.

Comment: K, that is a weird game :/

Answer (score 2):

In April, there will be another level unlocked. They're releasing missions once a month episodically.

Comment: Wow that is really bad. I thought episodic meant that they release one city at a time with a couple missions in each.

Comment: MrLemon's comment may be a bit overly hars (due to being an automatic message), but the answer could do with fleshing out when it comes to the publisher's known releas plans.

Comment: @DJPirtu I disagree. This answer really *doesn't* answer the question, nor does it even attempt to. The question also indicates that OP is already aware of the April release: "Nothing else until april?"

Comment: @MrLemon True, but I think the answer could be rather naturaly be appended with the intended release schedule (assuming this is publicly known). This would answer the asker's actual question and any possible questions of those who find this answer later on. But, as said, this requires fleshing out the answer. I agree that as is, it's hardly helpful at all.

Comment: @DJPirtu TBH, there is nothing else to add to his answer. The Paris mission is currently the only mission, as @CPK said: `They're releasing missions once a month episodically.`

Comment: Do you have a source for this?